# How to change column depending on user input?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, so I have some code in Excel VBA and what I'm struggling with is making it so that when I input a number let's say 3, the code firstly makes 3 new columns where to column R is and then makes 3 columns where the column W moved to. Is this possible? I was thinking something like column W + i but i don't know how to do that in VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
n = InputBox("How many columns do you want to add?")
For i = 1 To n
Columns("R:R").Select
Columns("R:R").Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next i
Columns("W:W").Select
Columns("W:W").Copy
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next i
End Sub
```

I dont know much about VBA so I just tried some experimenting with putting `Columns("W + i:W + i").Select` this as a line but it didn't work and I'm not even surprised.

Comment: Column W is always at the same position. I guess you mean that your data moves  to different column because you insert new columns, but W is always W. Make it in reserve order. First insert the 3 columns where W and then insert 3 columns in R (and whatever is in W will we moved too)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns how can I make it so it first repeats the action x times for the column W and the moves on to column R?

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim n As Long, s
    n = InputBox("How many columns do you want to add?")
    If n < 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    For Each s In Array("W:W", "R:R")
        With Columns(s)
            .Copy
            .Resize(, n).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
               CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End With
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```